# How can I set this to toggle the map view?

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to toggle the map view on my android map app - I have been told to use this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.mapview :
EVENT HERE TO TOGGLE MAP VIEW TO AND FROM SATELLITE 
default :
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

However, I added this code to the end of my map page code -- but i don't know what to put in the middle to make this menu item actually toggle from the different maps available. Help???

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, you should do something like that:

```
case R.id.mapview :
    myMapView.setSatellite(!myMapView.isSatellite());
    break;
```